# Simple HTTP server in Python. How to GET files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, webserver, httpserver, simplehttpserver

I have such code for running simple server on Python 3. I know that I can just use something like this `python -m http.server 8080`, however I want to understand how it works and set limits for serving files extensions.

I try to use `path.join(dir, 'index.html')`, but looks like that doesn't work.

```
>> TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

<>

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from os import path

hostName = "localhost"
hostPort = 8080

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    dir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
    content_type = 'text/html'

    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', self.content_type)
        self.send_header('Content-Length', path.getsize(self.getPath()))
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write(self.getContent(self.getPath()))

    def getPath(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            content_path = path.join(dir, 'index.html')
        else:
            content_path = path.join(dir, str(self.path))
        return content_path

    def getContent(self, content_path):
        with open(content_path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            content = f.read()
        return bytes(content, 'utf-8')

myServer = HTTPServer((hostName, hostPort), RequestHandler)
myServer.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Never overwrite a builtin name (In your example `dir`). Use something more helpful for readers (`BASE_DIRECTORY`) or something like that.

Comment: This is a simple scoping problem. In python you can't access the scope of a class inside its functions.

Answer (score 2):

[`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) is a builtin function. You're trying to join that function to the string `'index.html'`, hence the error.

---

The reason you're presumably confused is that you tried to hide `dir` with a string, here:

```
dir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
```

But when you put that inside a `class` definition, that doesn't create a global variable that hides the builtin, it creates a class attribute. To access a class attribute from within a method of that class, you have to do the same thing you do with a normal instance attribute:

```
content_path = path.join(self.dir, 'index.html')
```

The only differences between class attributes and instance attributes are that:

- All of your instances share the same `dir` attribute instead of each having their own copy.
- You can access it as `RequestHandler.dir` or `type(self).dir` instead of just as `self.dir`.

---

To avoid this kind of confusion, it's a good idea to avoid reusing the names of any of the builtin functions. While it's *legal* to do so, it often leads to mistakes just like this one, and makes it harder to debug those mistakes.

---

Also, given that `dir` is a constant across the entire program, just like `hostName` and `hostPort` are, and isn't all that closely tied to the `RequestHandler` type, maybe you just wanted a global constant, like `hostName`, instead of a class attribute.

Comment: @MAxShvedov Sorry, I don’t understand what you mean by that question.

Comment: I mean if I will use `dir_path = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))` as a global constant, how it should be called from a class?

Comment: @MAxShvedov The exact same way you use any global: just reference the name `dir_path`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Seems I rushed. Code works for `index.html` if it just request to `/`, but for other files it doesn't works. That's why trying to request files from `c:/` directory.